# How can I make that this will open another layout?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-activity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
```

(What i must i write here that app will open another activity?)

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (item.getItemId()){
   case R.id.action_settings:
       Intent i = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
       startActivity(i);
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this to open a new activity-

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case R.id.action_settings:
Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @divjad--- don't forget to add "NextActivity" in the manifest.xml